# Jekyll Build Error for v 3.1.2

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I began work on a Jekyll site on my home computer (a mac) and then came to work on my linux machine to continue working. I'm getting these errors when running 'jekyll serve'

```
from /home/gmsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-3.1.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:33:in `require_from_bundler'
from /home/gmsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jekyll-3.1.2/bin/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/gmsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /home/gmsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
from /home/gmsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/gmsdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

This is what I have installed:

```
gem: 'jekyll', '3.1.2'
gem 'jekyll-paginate'
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'rouge'
gem 'jekyll-gist'
gem 'jekyll-watch'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0.rc2'
gem 'rack-cache'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.1',
gem: 'Bundler'
gem 'rake'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rack-contrib'
```

Any ideas on how to continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle update
```

then

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bundler](//bundler.io) is a dependency manager, you don't need to require all gems required by Jekyll 3.1.2, just those which are not.

Also, there is an error on your Gemfile:

`gem: 'bundler'`

Bundler  shouldn't be there, nor `:`

There was also `:` on the first line.

So, reduce your Gemfile to:

```
gem 'jekyll', '3.1.2' 
gem 'jekyll-paginate' 
gem 'jekyll-gist' 
gem 'thin'
```

Just include the other rake gems if you really need them. For a standard Jekyll project, you won't.

Then you do as David said:

First run `bundle install`

Run `bundle update`

Serve Jekyll with bundler:

`bundle exec jekyll serve`

If you are on Linux, you might need to add `sudo` before each command.